# org.springframework.dao.TransientDataAccessResourceException: PreparedStatementCallback;

Tags: java

```
org.springframework.dao.TransientDataAccessResourceException: PreparedStatementCallback; SQL [ select id from employeerole where username = kiran and pin is NULL]; The index 1 is out of range.; nested exception is com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The index 1 is out of range.
    at org.springframework.jdbc.support.SQLStateSQLExceptionTranslator.doTranslate(SQLStateSQLExceptionTranslator.java:106)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.support.AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.translate(AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.java:72)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.support.AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.translate(AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.java:80)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.support.AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.translate(AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.java:80)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:607)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.query(JdbcTemplate.java:641)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.query(JdbcTemplate.java:670)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.query(JdbcTemplate.java:678)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.query(JdbcTemplate.java:710)
    at com.hcl.hips.service.DataService.fetchResults(DataService.java:75)
    at com.hcl.hips.action.Login.validate(Login.java:119)
    at com.hcl.hips.action.Login.execute(Login.java:63)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invokeAction(DefaultActionInvocation.java:440)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invokeActionOnly(DefaultActionInvocation.java:279)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:242)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.DefaultWorkflowInterceptor.doIntercept(DefaultWorkflowInterceptor.java:163)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:87)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:236)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.validator.ValidationInterceptor.doIntercept(ValidationInterceptor.java:249)
    at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.validation.AnnotationValidationInterceptor.doIntercept(AnnotationValidationInterceptor.java:68)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:87)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:236)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ConversionErrorInterceptor.intercept(ConversionErrorInterceptor.java:122)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:236)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ParametersInterceptor.doIntercept(ParametersInterceptor.java:195)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:87)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:236)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ParametersInterceptor.doIntercept(ParametersInterceptor.java:195)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:87)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:236)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.StaticParametersInterceptor.intercept(StaticParametersInterceptor.java:148)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:236)
    at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.CheckboxInterceptor.intercept(CheckboxInterceptor.java:93)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:236)
    at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.FileUploadInterceptor.intercept(FileUploadInterceptor.java:235)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:236)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ModelDrivenInterceptor.intercept(ModelDrivenInterceptor.java:89)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:236)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ScopedModelDrivenInterceptor.intercept(ScopedModelDrivenInterceptor.java:128)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:236)
    at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.ProfilingActivationInterceptor.intercept(ProfilingActivationInterceptor.java:104)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:236)
    at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.debugging.DebuggingInterceptor.intercept(DebuggingInterceptor.java:267)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:236)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ChainingInterceptor.intercept(ChainingInterceptor.java:126)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:236)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.PrepareInterceptor.doIntercept(PrepareInterceptor.java:138)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:87)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:236)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.I18nInterceptor.intercept(I18nInterceptor.java:148)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:236)
    at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.ServletConfigInterceptor.intercept(ServletConfigInterceptor.java:164)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:236)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.AliasInterceptor.intercept(AliasInterceptor.java:128)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:236)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ExceptionMappingInterceptor.intercept(ExceptionMappingInterceptor.java:176)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:236)
    at org.apache.struts2.impl.StrutsActionProxy.execute(StrutsActionProxy.java:52)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.serviceAction(Dispatcher.java:468)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.ExecuteOperations.executeAction(ExecuteOperations.java:77)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.doFilter(StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.java:76)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at net.sf.j2ep.ProxyFilter.doFilter(ProxyFilter.java:91)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at com.hcl.hips.action.LoginFilter.doFilter(LoginFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:128)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:293)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11AprProcessor.process(Http11AprProcessor.java:859)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11AprProtocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11AprProtocol.java:574)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$Worker.run(AprEndpoint.java:1527)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
Caused by: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The index 1 is out of range.
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException.makeFromDriverError(Unknown Source)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerPreparedStatement.setterGetParam(Unknown Source)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerPreparedStatement.setString(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.DelegatingPreparedStatement.setString(DelegatingPreparedStatement.java:132)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.StatementCreatorUtils.setValue(StatementCreatorUtils.java:335)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.StatementCreatorUtils.setParameterValueInternal(StatementCreatorUtils.java:217)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.StatementCreatorUtils.setParameterValue(StatementCreatorUtils.java:145)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.ArgPreparedStatementSetter.setValues(ArgPreparedStatementSetter.java:51)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate$1.doInPreparedStatement(JdbcTemplate.java:646)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:591)
    ... 78 more
```

Comment: Guys Please help me to find out the soltion for the above code

Comment: we just have an exception  here.. maybe you could post the code where the exception is thrown

Comment: Please, next time dedicate a little more time/effort to formulate your question. This question doesn't even have a title and only consists of an unformatted stack trace. We're not `catch` blocks.

Comment: `@kiran kumar` You have refused to tell us what is here -> `com.hcl.hips.service.DataService.fetchResults(DataService.java:75)`

Answer (score 2):

Just guessing, because you haven't shown anything but a stack trace, but I'd say that you're creating a `PreparedStatement` with the query

```
select id from employeerole where username = kiran and pin is NULL
```

and you're later invoking `setString(1, someString)` on the `PreparedStatement` (by means of [`StatementCreatorUtils#setParameterValue()`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/1.1.5/api/org/springframework/jdbc/core/StatementCreatorUtils.html))

To use `setString` with a `PreparedStatement` you'd have to have a query with parameters (`?` ) on it. In that query you don't have any parameters but you're also setting a value for parameter #1.

For further reference on PreparedStatements, I'd recommend taking a read, at least, at this tutorial: [Using Prepared Statements](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html)

Just to add, if the `username` column is a character-typed column, you'll have to quote the String `kiran` in your sql query.

Note that `PreparedStatements` handle that for you when using a parameterized query. Aside from that advantage it's the most basic protection against [SQL Injection](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/SQL_Injection), because it also escapes parameters as needed.